# Dynamically look for index() in list from set of options

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def _parse_options(productcode_array):
    if not self._check_productcode_has_options(productcode_array):
        return None
    possible_options = {"UV1", "UV2", "Satin", "Linen", "Unco", "Natural"}
    option_index = productcode_array.index()
```

Example value of `productcode_array`:

```
["BC", "1.5x3.5", "100lb", "Linen", "Q100"]
```

My initial thought was to maybe `try/except` with a list comprehension but I feel there's probably a cleaner way I don't know about.

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the index position within my list `productcode_array` where any 1 of the `possible_options` exist. I know there will always only be 1 of the options present. The reason I need this is because the index position within the productcode is dependent on a number of factors.

What would be a clean and effective way to use `index()` with each of the values of my `possible_options` set?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in `possible_options` always exists only one value that is present in `option_index` and you need to find index of this value in `option_index` list?

Comment: @AndrejKesely correct, yes. I did post an answer below that worked for me in a repl, but am still open to refactoring options that don't require me to use `try/except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> next(i for i, code in enumerate(productcode_array) if code in possible_options)
3
```

or

```
>>> productcode_array.index(possible_options.intersection(productcode_array).pop())
3
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about using `next()` but that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Example with `try/except`:

```
for x in possible_options:
  try:
    option_index = productcode_array.index(x)
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

This does work, but it feels dirty, so open to cleaner options.

Comment: This isn't "dirty". This is perfectly normal and pythonic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Meh... that's looping through a `set` and repeatedly searching in a `list`. Rather the wrong way around. Wouldn't call it perfectly normal and pythonic.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you're right, it should be the other way around with enumerate, like the accepted answer. Just without the `next(<genexpr>)` madness, which I hate

Answer (score 1):

You could use `set.intersection` and then assign to `option_index` (assuming there's only one common value, as stated in the comments):

For example:

```
possible_options = {"UV1", "UV2", "Satin", "Linen", "Unco", "Natural"}
productcode_array = ["BC", "1.5x3.5", "100lb", "Linen", "Q100"]

for v in possible_options.intersection(productcode_array):
    option_index = productcode_array.index(v)

print(option_index)
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of the `intersection` method. Went with the answer above using `next()`, but this was helpful!